# DIV inline-block not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have five columns which I aligned using `display:inline-block` It works fine, but there is one problem. When I refresh the page for about 4 or 5 times while the first column is on the top the other 4 columns go to the bottom of it and when I refresh again it gets back to its original place. I couldn't figure out what is causing this and the content inside the columns are coming from database. can someone give me hint?

**CSS**

```
    .col1
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:225px;
}

.col2
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:225px;
}

.col3
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:225px;
}

.col4
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:225px;
}

.col5
{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:225px;
}

.col_content_wrap
{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow:4px 4px 1px #eee;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.imgwrap
{
    height:169px;
    position:relative;
    width:223px;
}

.price_wrap
{
    border-top:1px solid silver;
    height:50px;
}

.price
{
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div clas="col1">
  <div class="col_content_wrap>
  <div class="imgwrap">image here
   <div class="price_wrap"><div class="price">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>



<div clas="col2">
  <div class="col_content_wrap>
  <div class="imgwrap">image here
   <div class="price_wrap"><div class="price">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


 <div clas="col3">
  <div class="col_content_wrap>
  <div class="imgwrap">image here
   <div class="price_wrap"><div class="price">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


  <div clas="col4">
  <div class="col_content_wrap>
  <div class="imgwrap">image here
   <div class="price_wrap"><div class="price">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>



  <div clas="col5">
  <div class="col_content_wrap>
  <div class="imgwrap">image here
   <div class="price_wrap"><div class="price">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: JSFiddle would be helpful here.

Comment: set overflow:hidden or post a jsfiddle

Comment: please use comma for same css selectors: `.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5 { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an endquote for each of the `<div class="col_content_wrap>` elements.

Also, in each of your html blocks, you have 5 `<div>`'s and only 4 `</div>`'s

Comment: In addition, `div clas="col1"` should be div `class="col1"` (`class` is misspelled)

Comment: I made mistakes while typing as I didn't copy paste original code because it has a lot of php code inside each column.